# Stopping VBScript executing when page loads

Tags: html, vbscript, onsubmit

I have a form that submits to a different page to the one it is on. I want to catch the onsubmit for the form and perfom some VBScript code.

Am I right in thinking like with Java code in a JSP, everything in <% %> will be evaluated before the html is rendered?

Here is a brief overview of my problem:

```
<form id="frm1" method="post" action="otherSite" onsubmit="<% logFormSubmit "submitted"%>">
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

The code in the onsubmit calls a sub, logFormSubmit on another asp page that takes a string argument as the action to be logged. The problem here is this happens before the form is submitted, because the <% %> code is evaluated before any html, or at least that's what I think is happening.

I can't log from he page the form submits to. Any suggestions on only calling the logFormSubmit sub when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the form values programmatically, call the logFormSubmit function, and then return false for the submit form.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The page that the form submits to does not belong to me and I am not able to edit it so can't catch the form values that way. I have done something similar before but only when a form submits to itself. Given that I can't edit the target page, I'm not sure this is possible?

Comment: Answer no longer required. Thanks.